# Django. Отменить авто-генерацию атрибута id в поле формы

Tags: django

Штатная ситуация - при создании формы из модели `django` генерирует для каждого поля свой атрибут `id` вида:

```
id = "id_<fieldname>"
```

Необходимо, чтобы поля формы не содержали только атрибут `id`, т.к. форма может рекурсивно появляться на странице, и делать уникальными `id` бесполезно, тем более, что можно обойтись и без него.

**Модель:**

```
class EntryEdit(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    editMarker = models.DateField()
    saveMarker = models.DateTimeField()
```

**Форма:**

```
class EntryEdit(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:    
        model = EntryEdit
        fields = ['editMarker']
    widgets = { 'editMarker': forms.DateInput(format=('%d.%m.%Y'), attrs={'class':'form-control', }) }
```

**Каким способом возможно отменить авто-создание `id` в полях формы?**

Comment: покажите саму форму и, на всякий случай, модель

Comment: Добавлены модель и форма.